# What's the best Java data structure for multiple values with same key?

Tags: java, data-structures

I need something like:

```
Bill | 1
Bill | 2
Bill | 3
George | 4
Sue | 5
Sue | 6
```

and when I ask for Bill's values I get back 1, 2, 3

Thanks!

Comment: Looks to me like you should be using the Numbers as the Key and the names as the value... If you can't, then store an ArrayList or something similar for Value

Comment: Try a `Map<String, List<Integer>>` or `Map<String, int[]>`.

Comment: If not all the items have the same type but are related, likely they can be modeled as a composing type, or holder. Example: `class Foo { Bar bar; Baz baz ; ...}` and `Map<Key, Foo>`.